# While learning Ruby, Sinatra, working on a project, yield error happened

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In my project, I have a few files: 
**1. main.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
set :public_folder, 'public'  
set :views, 'views'
set :erb, :layout => :base
get '/' do
erb :layout
end
get '/about' do
erb :about
end
get '/contact' do
erb :contact
end
```

**2. layout.erb**

```html
<% title="Songs By Sinatra" %>
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>
      <%=title %>
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1><%= title %></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/" title="Home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/about" title="About">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/contact" title="Contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
      <%=yield %>
    </section>
  </body>

  </html>
  <p>Welcome to this website that's all about the songs of the great Frank Sinatra.</p>
  <img src="/images/sinatra.jpg" alt="Frank Sinatra">
```

**3. about.erb**

```html
<p>
  This site is a demonstration of how to build a website using Sinatra.
</p>
```

When I go to http://localhost:4567/about everything is OK, page loads, but when I go to http://localhost:4567/, I get an error: **no block given (yield).**

Can anyone explain what is the problem, and possible solution.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "ruby-on-rails"?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a block in

```
erb :layout
```

For  `<%=yield %>` in `layout.erb` to work, you need to pass a block whose output will be placed at the location of `yield.  In its simplest form, you can do something like this:

```
erb :layout { "This is what I want in output" }
```

Typically, you render another template:

```
erb :layout do 
   erb :about
end
```

More details in [documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Templates%20with%20%3Ccode%3Eyield%3C/code%3E%20and%20nested%20layouts).

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; what @wandmaker says - you need to pass a block to :layout.

Understanding `yield` is essential for understanding Ruby.  Basically, `yield` passes control from one scope to another.  All methods in Ruby accept blocks but they ignore them unless they explicitly yield or call them:

```
"A RUBY STRING".downcase { p "I'm in a block!" }
# => "a ruby string"
```

But if the method calls yield, control is passed to the block and then passed back to the calling scope:

```
def yield_me
  yield
end

yield_me { p "I'm in a block!" }
# => "I'm in a block!"
```

Alternatively, you can catch blocks as arguments:

```
def catch_me(&block)
  block.call
end

catch_me { p "I'm in a block" }
# => "I'm in a block!"
```

So with that in mind, it should be clearer what your Sinatra template is doing - it renders layout.erb but when it hits `yield`, it tries to yield control to a block - in this case a non-existent one.

So all your responses should supply a block or sub-template like:

```
erb :layout { "<p>This is the about page</p>" }
```

or

```
erb :index
```